# Has PHP get_meta_tags stopped working?

Tags: php, get-meta-tags

So I'm trying to get the meta tags from a URL where I'd normally use `get_meta_tags` but it no longer seems to work properly? I'm trying to get a description and image from them and my site is over HTTPS (if that's relevant). Am I using it incorrectly or is there now an alternative method to scrape this data in 2017, I've tried multiple ways with no luck so far and can't find anything in Google/SO suggesting I'm doing anything differently to anyone else.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://facebook.com');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags);
```

**Facebook Output**

```
Array
(
    [referrer] => default
    [robots] => noodp,noydir
)
```

**Youtube Output**

```
Array
(
    [description] => Enjoy the videos and music you love, upload original content, and share it all with friends, family, and the world on YouTube.
    [keywords] => video, sharing, camera phone, video phone, free, upload
    [theme-color] => #ff0000
)
```

Comment: Facebook does not want people to scrape their pages (because that is mostly done by people who want to interact with content, but don’t want to use the API), and has a handful of measures in place against it.

Comment: You can inspect the Facebook page, and you'll find there is very few content in the meta tag. So it's on the Facebook site, not the php function.

Comment: Ok so basically no one supports meta tags anymore.. Back to the drawing board!